# How to use Gtk.StyleContext.remove_provider() in Python?

Tags: python, css, gtk3

I am trying to change the background color of Gtkbutton widgets via css style providers.

I can successfully change the color to any valid css color via the following:

```
class Widget_Color(object):
def set_widget_background_color(widget_object, new_color):
    """
    Sets the background-color of widget_opject to new_color.
    The value of new_color must be a string representing a valid
    css color name or the HEX code of a valid css color. The string is not case sensitive
    """

    css = '* {background-color: ' + new_color + '; }'
    css = css.encode('utf-8')
    css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
    css_provider.load_from_data(css)
    widget_style_context = widget_object.get_style_context()
    widget_style_context.add_provider(css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

From the GTK documentation [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/StyleContext.html#Gtk.StyleContext.remove_provider):

> remove_provider(provider)[source]
>   Parameters: provider (Gtk.StyleProvider) – a Gtk.StyleProvider
>   Removes provider from the style providers list in self.

I understand that I should use the remove_provider method to later remove the change I made and return the background color to default.

However I cannot find the style providers list.  In the context of my code I can't understand what self is when I need to find the style providers list.

Where is the style providers list?

Answer (score 0):

After further research and searching I decided to give up on add_provider() and remove_provider() approach and instead was successful with add_class() and remove_class() as shown in the code below.

```
class Widget_Color(object):
def set_widget_background_color(widget_object, new_color):
    """
    Sets the background-color of widget_opject to new_color.
    The value of new_color must be a string representing a valid
    css color name or the HEX code of a valid css color. The string is not case sensitive
    """

    css = '.custom {background-color: ' + new_color + '; }'
    css = css.encode('utf-8')
    css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
    css_provider.load_from_data(css)
    widget_style_context = widget_object.get_style_context()
    widget_style_context.add_provider(css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
    widget_style_context.add_class('custom')

def set_default_widget_style(widget_object):
    widget_style_context = widget_object.get_style_context()
    widget_style_context.remove_class('custom')
```